# Linux mint 17.2 rafaela upgrade wizard not appearing

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade

I have Linux Mint 17 and intended to upgrade to 17.2 using the upgrade wizard. The "Upgrade to Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela" option appears in the edit menu of the Update Manager, but when I click it nothing happens.

I assume there is some error occurring preventing the wizard from starting. Is there a way to see logs from the Update Manager? Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this out by my self.

Ran `/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/mintupdate-launcher` to see the logs. Turned out there were permission problems for some repository list.

```
SystemError: E:Opening /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)
```

After fixing the permissions the wizard worked.